# SQL query on one to many relationship with multiple filters

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, one-to-many

I have some experience with SQL but I still couldn't find out how can I do the following query performance efficient.

I have 2 tables - `Box` and `Item`. `Box` has `id` attribute which is the primary key (and some more), and `Item` has `box_id`, `type`, `name`. Each table has billions of records, each box has on average 10 items.
**I want to query all the boxes that have at least one item with a given type, and at least one item with a given name (could be the same item or different).** The query should be paginated with page size of 10.
I used single column indexing on all `Item` attributes. The following query for that (the first page) takes a very long duration (more than a minute):

`SELECT Box.id FROM Box WHERE 
(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Item WHERE Item.box_id = Box.id AND Item.type = 'my_type')) AND
(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Item WHERE Item.box_id = Box.id AND Item.name = 'my_name'))
LIMIT 10`

I think that the problem is making the intersection between boxes filtered in each part of the query (querying with just one of the constraints returns about million records). I am using Aurora PostgreSQL 9.6.6.

Comment: I think this is the typo based your description this suggests me to correct with this : `AND Item.name = 'my_name'` instead of `AND Item.type = 'my_name'`.

Comment: Please produce an explain plan with actual timings, and add it as part of the question, as in: `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  <-- your query here.

Comment: Do you want "**all the boxes**", or just 10 of them (`LIMIT 10`)?

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes DBMS (including version), a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (including input) & diffable expected output. Show that your program calculates what you expect it to as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. Justify "minimal code with a problem" for required functionality by also giving code that works for a maximal part of that functionality. Ask about the (small) difference between the examples. (Debugging basics.) PS See edit help re code block format.

Comment: I have updated the question. This example is a simplified version of my exact case, so running explain will show many irrelevant outputs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't responded to the clarifications so I will assume a few things:

- You want ALL the boxes, not just 10 of them.
- There's a typo when comparing by name. Should be: `Item.name = 'my_name'`
- You said "I have indexed all Item attributes." I would assume you have single column indexes for all the columns of the `Item` table.
- The column `id` of Box is the primary key, and therefore it already has an index on it.

Now, my take is the indexes you are using are not optimal for this query since they only include columns separately. If you don't already have them, please try creating the following indexes:

```
create index ix1 on Item (box_id, type);

create index ix2 on Item (box_id, name);
```

Yes, both of them. Try the query again and see how long does it take.

If still slow, please post the explain plan, using:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT Box.id 
  FROM Box 
  WHERE 
(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Item WHERE Item.box_id = Box.id AND Item.type = 'my_type')) 
  AND
(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Item WHERE Item.box_id = Box.id AND Item.name = 'my_name'))
```

Comment: When a question is not clear please comment asking for clarification. Guessing at answers leads to messes.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question. Your assumptions are correct. Did you mean indexing (box_id, name) and (box_id, type)?

Comment: Yes. It's fixed now.

Comment: Seems that changing the indexing to what you proposed helped. My problem is more complicated than that, but it's a helpful advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`INTERSECT` is another option.

```
  SELECT Box_id FROM Item
  WHERE Item.type = 'my_type'
  INTERSECT
  SELECT Box_id FROM Item 
  WHERE Item.name = 'my_name'
```

Note: INTERSECT returns distinct values so no need for an outer query to get the list of distinct Box_id values that meet your criteria. This query does return orphan items (items with a box_id not in the box table) so an outer query might be required if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Box.id) Box.*
FROM Box
  JOIN Item I1 ON I1.box_id = Box.id AND I1.type = 'my_type'
  JOIN Item I2 ON I2.box_id = Box.id AND I2.name = 'my_name'
ORDER BY Box.id;
```

`JOIN`s filters results by item's type and name.

Comment: Though correct in terms of results, I don't see how this query is faster.

Comment: Me too. So waiting for OP to try and respond